# Java_Home problem, i can't find java's path

Tags: java

I try to change environment but it didn't work.

I think I wrote wrong the path for Java. I write this `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`.

How can I find the true Java path ?

Comment: What's the result of `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
echo path result is this echo $JAVA_HOME has not result

Comment: Could you also run `java -version`

Comment: java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: If you were able to execute `java -version`, without path from any dir, then your install of Java is working. Could you be more precise about your problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You have java 1.7 installed, as I see from `java -version`

If you want to know where is some executed command is located - use `which` command.

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Quote from man:

```
DESCRIPTION
       which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be exe‐
       cuted in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  com‐
       mands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching
       the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.  It
       does not follow symbolic links.
```

But usually `/usr/bin/java` is [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), so to identify real location of java binary use `namei` command.

```
$ namei /usr/bin/java
f: /usr/bin/java
 d /
 d usr
 d bin
 l java -> /etc/alternatives/java
   d /
   d etc
   d alternatives
   l java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
     d /
     d usr
     d lib
     d jvm
     d java-8-oracle
     d jre
     d bin
     - java
```

As you can see, in my case, my `java` command is linked to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`. Java itself located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. So JAVA_HOME variable should look like:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

If you do this steps you can find your JAVA_HOME, my bet that it is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 0):

type this command: `update-alternatives --display java`

for example on my system it displays:

```
java - manual mode
link currently points to /opt/java6/bin/java
/opt/java6/bin/java - priority 1
/opt/java7/bin/java - priority 2
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'.
```

If you take a look at the second row, it tells me the path of my default JDK

Comment: java - manual mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1072
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java'.

Comment: then your `JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`

Comment: This solved my problem. +1